# Comparing inputs and outputs - bash

Tags: linux, bash

Say i have an input file and an output file (test.in and test.out) and a program "./myprogram" with standard input redirected to come from test.in and use the results that are captured from standard output to be compared with test.out

how exactly can i compare

Im Thinking,

```
 if [ $(myprogram < test.in) == $(cat test.out) ]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Use `cmp`<sup>†</sup> and specify `-` as one of the files to compare, which tells it to use stdin.

```
if myprogram < test.in | cmp -s - test.out; then
```

If you want to compare the output of two commands without creating temp files, use the `<(cmd)` feature. (Search for "Process Substitution" in `man bash`.)

```
if cmp -s <(myprogram < test1.in) <(myprogram < test2.in); then
```

<sup>†</sup> Or `diff` if you want to know what the differences are.

Comment: the `-` is suppose to be a file ?

Comment: do i have to make a tmp file to comapre the .out file with the actual results of the program with .in inputs ?

Comment: @Beginnernato Most shell programs treat `-` as shorthand for stdin. It can also be accessed via the pseudo-file `/dev/stdin`.

Comment: so the `-` is taking the result from `program < test.in` and comparing it with `test.out` ?

Comment: since when im testing your code its saying the expected output and the output from the test.out file dont equal each other, when they actually do ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use diff.  Something like this:

`if cat test.in | myprogram | diff - test.out`

Comment: Probably also use the `-q` (quiet) option for diff.

Comment: Yeah, although "quiet" still does print out some information.